# NodeJS development on Azure virtual machine

Tags: node.js, azure, docker

Currently, I have one Ubuntu server on Azure. I am using Webstorm to develop NodeJS on Surface 3. So, can I use vagrant or any technique to sync code on my Surface to Ubuntu after saving file?

Comment: It isn't really clear what you are asking, can you clarify what it is you are trying to do, have you tried syncing said code? did it work? did you get errors? As it stands your question is likely to be closed as not being clear what you're asking. (and too broad)

Comment: HI, this is really a question. I want to use Surface 3 like a editor. After saving, code will be sync to Ubuntu server on Azure and run it on Ubuntu server. Can we do it? and How?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think we can leverage Vagrant to manage your VMs on Azure. You can use the [Vagrant Azure Provider](https://github.com/Azure/vagrant-azure) which is a Vagrant 1.7.3+ plugin that adds Microsoft Azure provider to Vagrant, allowing Vagrant to control and provision machines in Microsoft Azure.

And you can refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/videos/azure-virtual-machine-creation-and-set-up-using-vagrant-with-corey-fowler/ for the video of how to create a VM on Azure using Vagrant.